# Storing session value in long type

Tags: java, scala, session, playframework, session-cookies

I am  storing id as a string in session in play framework with scala.

```
Redirect("/").withSession("userId" -> id.toString)
```

I want to know is it possible to store it in Long type, because every time when i have to use it i am converting it again into Long again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Well the Http Header that you receive is an ascii string.

And hence on setting header or on receiving, you will manually have to convert your cookie pair (`userId`) to String and and back to `Long` respectively